# Calculating a sum, grouped by columns, from a CSV file in awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am new to Bash. I have a CSV file with four columns and values are separated by a comma:

```
jack,england,498,a
roy,wales,344,b
ben,ireland,679,a
ron,scotland,895,a
emma,england,344,a
jason,scotland,566,a
ketty,wales,433,b
```

My output should be like this:

```
england,842
ireland,679
scotland,1461
wales,777
```

City names must be alphabetically sorted and output should print on terminal only.

Here is my code:

```
#! /bin/awk -f
awk '{a[$1" "$2]+=$3}END{for (i in a){print i,a[i]}}' file.csv | sort -k2
```

When I am running this code with  `awk -f file.awk` it gives me a syntax error. I have read many answers about this question but none helps me.

```
invalid char in expression  '''
```

syntax error just after `awk`.

Comment: BTW, why `$1" "$2` as the index, when you only want to sum by `$2`?

Comment: Soory for that I was  just trying to run my code and see what is the output .I know how to handle that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script is a shell script that calls awk, not an awk script. So it's perfectly correct, except for the `#!/bin/awk -f`.

Use a `#!/bin/sh` shebang, **or** fix it to be pure awk code.

---

The latter might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gawk -f

BEGIN {
  # gawk extension: iterate over for loop in sort order (so we don't need to pipe to sort)
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"

  # split on commas
  FS=OFS=","
}

{
  a[$2]+=$3
}

END {
  for (i in a) {
    print i, a[i]
  }
}
```

Comment: sir I have to make an awk  script  and running command should be awk -f file.awk file.csv

Comment: If you put `awk -f` instead the script, it's not an awk script. That's **shell** syntax, not awk syntax.

Comment: And you absolutely can run this with `awk -f file.awk file.csv`, **if** your `awk` is GNU awk; `gawk` just makes sure we don't run with any other version.

Comment: just curious what if I have to print city names in reverse alphabetical order  from Z to A

Comment: That would be `@ind_str_desc`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html

Comment: now sir it is printing the file.csv input multiple times on terminal   but We want only  final output after addition

Comment: Make sure you're using my current code, as-edited. There've been several prior revisions, one of which had that bug (on account of not putting the assignments in a BEGIN block).

Comment: `^1` but `FS=","` -> `FS=OFS=","` to get the comma separator in the output.

Answer (score 2):

Short GNU ***[datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/)*** solution:

```
datamash -st, -g 2 sum 3 < file.csv
```

The output:

```
england,842
ireland,679
scotland,1461
wales,777
```